# How to retrieve URL fragment parameters in drf APIView?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have created a callback view for instagram account connection in django by inheriting the `APIView` class.

After successful connection of instagram account facebook redirects me to the `InstagramConnectCallbackView` and includes the response data as a URL fragment.

**url:**

```
http://localhost:8000/v1/instagram-connect/callback/?#access_token=EAAN....&data_access_expiration_time=1650543346&expires_in=6254&state=eyd...
```

But I don't know how to read the URL fragments from the request into the `get` method.

**callback view:**

```
class InstagramConnectCallbackView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    version = settings.FACEBOOK_GRAPH_API_VERSION

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        ....
```

I tried the following:

```
request.get_full_path() # returns `/v1/instagram-connect/callback/`
request.query_params()  # returns `{}`
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: did you tried like this **``request.GET['access_token']``**

Comment: @AnkitTiwari `request.GET['access_token']` didn't work coz `request.GET` returns query parameters & my access token is in fragment parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `query_params` as

```
request.query_params.get('your_key_name')
```

If you want `default` then yot can use

```
self.request.query_params.get('your_key_name', None)
```

In your case you can `get` values like

```
access_token = self.request.query_params.get('access_token', None)
data_access_expiration_time = self.request.query_params.get('data_access_expiration_time', None)
expires_in = self.request.query_params.get('expires_in', None)

and so on ...
```

Comment: It didn't work coz `request.query_params` returns query parameters & my access token is in fragment parameters.

Comment: Hello @AjayLingayat by looking at url you provided your ``access_token`` comes after ``?`` so it is called as parameter read more about [parametrs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM_parameters)

Comment: @AnkitTiwari no the access token comes after the hash symbol, so that makes it a URL fragment parameter.

Comment: then your key should be like this **``request.GET['#access_token']``**